# How to restart mysql slave node?

Tags: mysql, replication

i have 8 slave servers and i need to restart one of them but in my.cnf file master-host, master-user etc. variables dont exists. So if i restart server as indicated [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5528/rebooting-a-mysql-replication-slave)
replication will start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replication configuration (which master to sync from, which relay log & which change it's up to) isn't stored in the my.cnf, it's stored in the master.info / relay.info files, so you should be OK to follow that process.